# On pullback of global sections of invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, global-dimension

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a dominant/surjective morphism of projective schemes and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf. Is it true that $H^0(\mathcal{L})=H^0(f^*\mathcal{L})$?

The fact I am not totally sure of is whether $H^0(f^*\mathcal{L})=H^0(f_*f^*\mathcal{L})$? If this is true then the statement follows from the projection formula.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not true in general. In fact
$$
H^0(X,f^*L) = H^0(Y,f_*f^*L) \cong H^0(Y,L \otimes f_*O_X),
$$
so as soon as the natural morphism $O_Y \to f_*O_X$ is not an isomorphism (for instance, if $f$ is finite of degree $d \ge 2$) and $L$ is sufficiently ample, this is not equal to $H^0(Y,L)$.